# How to retrieve a Bitmap/image from videoview

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a snapshot of the current position of playback of a video, but I couldn't find an appropriate way to do that. Is there a method I can use?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VideoView extends SurfaceView, so it seems there is no easy way to do it. Take a look at this post: http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/c4720072d659f4f0/9b207dc411c5e800?lnk=raot

You may need to read the movie raw file, implement your own drawing mechanism, and access directly the file instead of the Canvas for the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you!! I figured there's probably no existing functions for me to do that, but I did not expect that this is that hard to do...

Comment: Well, she is not just another anonymous reply on the web: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html , so I would consider her word quite highly.